# How to make Material UI backdrop stronger/dimmer?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

The default appearance of the material UI backdrop isn't very dark. I want to make it dimmer (i.e. "more black").

Answer (score 1):

You can style it using the `.MuiBackdrop-root` class with the `rgba()` css function

```
.MuiBackdrop-root {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

The final value (.7) represents the "strength" of the dimness